# Macbook Pro Connecting to External Monitor

Tags: macbook-pro, display, resolution

I am wondering why my MacBook pro retina screen gets cut off from the sides while connecting an external monitor. My monitor is LCD 1280 x 1024 resolution connected via display port to VGA adapter. Other monitors I have used with same resolution do not give same issue. Other monitor I tried was bigger in screen size but same resolution. Please explain. I have attached image of what happens. [image]

Comment: Are you mirroring your output?

Answer (score 1):

From what I can see of your other monitor, it looks like you're in mirroring mode. Go to System Preferences > Displays > toggle "Mirror Displays", [or press <kbd>Cmd</kbd><kbd>F1</kbd>](https://www.macobserver.com/tips/quick-tip/os-x-use-keyboard-shortcut-display-mirroring/.) (maybe <kbd>Cmd</kbd><kbd>Fn</kbd><kbd>F1</kbd>).